# Fixing a button to the bottom of a sidebar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm making a sidebar in bootstrap and would like to have a logout button fixed to the bottom of the sidebar. How would I accomplish this? I've included a fiddle of the code I'm using:
http://jsfiddle.net/ukcfdm77/

The actual website of this example is here:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/
```

Comment: check my edit; should be what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

so if that were your actual sidebar, you could just add your logout button like this:

## update

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fq8tqc4m/38/)

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" hidden>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
    <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
    <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="logout_sidebar_button" class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li><a href="#">Signout</a></li>
  </ul>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

#logout_sidebar_button {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
}

.sidebar {
    color: white;
    background:hsl(227, 49%, 89%);
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 260px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.sidebar li {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

## update 2

absolute elements will be positioned relative to their closest **positioned** ancestor (i.e. realtive, absolute, fixed). In your case, it was positioned relative to the fixed container, not it's parent. Here's the fix.

demo 2: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hqvLujy4/11/)

```
#sidebar_content {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: sorry not using your js fiddle just copy/past pertinent code. My jsfiddle resizes weird and I can see the results.

Comment: This is how I thought it should be done, but it doesn't seem to work. The website is responsive so you might need to widen the results pane to see the sidebar.

Comment: This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/hqvLujy4/ -- It seems to work well, but when the window height is made too small the log out button seems to overlap over the other buttons. How can this be fixed?

Comment: you'd do it as I did In my answer. check edit in min.

Comment: Also, since you're using my code, will you mark as correct?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -4):

Adding a `btn btn-*` class to the `<a>` tag will do the trick. In the code replace `<a href="">Logout</a>` with this

```
<li>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Logout</a>
</li>
```